# Is it possible to pass a value from Adapter to Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have `Activity1`, `Activity1 Adapter` and `Activity2`

I'm not able to pass value between an Adapter and Activity. When back button is pressed, I'm expecting a value to be coming from the Second Activity (`Activity 2`) to `Activity1` Currently, it gives me `null`

Here are my code snippets.

**Activity1 Adapter**

```
 holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity origin = (Activity) context;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("searchText", staggeredCustomCard.getSearchText());
                origin.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
```

**Activity2**

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.getStringExtra("searchText");
        setResult(1, mIntent);
    }
```

I'm expecting this `searchText` to be going to `Activity1`. Could anyone please guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `getStringExtra("searchText");` from a completely new intent, that's why it's returning null. You need to get search text from `getIntent()` like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        String search = getIntent().getStringExtra("searchText");
        mIntent.putExtra("searchText", search);
        setResult(1, mIntent);
    }
```

Comment: `onBackPressed()` is not even getting called. I put the `Log` statements but nothing seem to be shown on LogCat.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I had to override this method `onSupportNavigateUp()` to make the `onBackPressed()` method work.